# Explanation of the steps on calculating the length of the catenary

Tags: integration, trigonometry, proof-explanation

Can someone please explain to me what identities have been used in the calculation of the below example and why the limits of integration change from $0$ to $a$? I have tried $\sinh^2{ t} = [-1 + \cosh (2 t)]/2$ and end up with nothing like the form below.

**Example**:

The catenary, is the shape of a wire hanging under its own weight and is given by

$$
x(t) = t{\bf{e}}_1 + \cosh{t} {\bf{e}}_2,$$
with $I = [−a,a]$.

The total length of this catenary is

\begin{align}
L &=\int_ {a}^{−a} {\sqrt{1 + \sinh^2{ t}}} \quad dt \\
&=2\int_0^a \cosh{t} \quad dt \\
&=2\sinh{a}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as we have the identity $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$, so do we have the identity
$$\cosh^2t-\sinh^2t=1$$
Thus $\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}=\cosh t$ and
$$L=\int_{-a}^a\sqrt{1+\sinh^2t}\,dt=\int_{-a}^a\cosh t\,dt$$
$\cosh$ is an even function, and for even functions the integral from $-a$ to $a$ is twice the integral from 0 to $a$.
$$\int_{-a}^a\cosh t\,dt=2\int_0^a\cosh t\,dt$$
The antiderivative of $\cosh$ is $\sinh$, like how the antiderivative of $\cos$ is $\sin$:
$$2\int_0^a\cosh t\,dt=2[\sinh t]_0^a=2\sinh a$$

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

The following identities/facts have been used:

- For any function $f:[-a,a] \to \mathbb{R} $ which is both even and integrable, $\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx = 2 \int_{0}^af(x) dx $. This explains the change in the limits of integration.
- For any real number $t$, $1+ \sinh ^2(t) = \cosh ^2 (t)$.
- For any non-negative real number $x$, $|x| = \sqrt{x^2} = x$, used in conjunction with the fact that $\cosh ^2 (t) > 0$, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

$\textit{Side note:}$ The last point is important to be aware of. We cannot always make the simplification $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, as it fails when $x < 0$.